# calculating the battery amperes to connect with UPS?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, amperage

I have 500 watt UPS, which outputs 220v and 50Hz. The calculation says that I need 500/12v = 41.67 Ampere and 12v battery to use with this UPS. But mostly people around me suggested 120A/h battery. What is the logic behind? In Pakistan the Electricity be available only for one hour and then one hour load shedding. What is the exact ampere ratings for the battery to use with 500 watt UPS, and how much amperes are required to charge that battery with in one hour. UPS is made of 12v and Lead acid battery charger.

Comment: Amps is not the reciprocal of Volts.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing up units.  Until you use the units correctly, you really can't understand what is going on.

A battery stores *energy*, which can be expressed in units like Joules or Watt-hours.  Energy moved around over time is *power*, which can be expressed in units like Watts.  You are specifying how fast the UPS is to deliver energy (500 W), but that doesn't tell you how much total energy needs to be delivered, from which you can work backwards and decide how much energy the battery needs to be able to deliver.

At full power, you say the UPS is delivering 500 W.  Let's say it is 80% effecient.  That means the battery has to deliver 625 W.  If this is a 12 V battery, then the current it is delivering into the UPS is 625W / 12V = 52 A.  That possible but quite a lot.  Are you really sure this UPS uses 12 V batteries, and not perhaps 24 V or even 48 V?

In any case, the figure you are completely missing is how long the UPS must be able to supply these 500 W.  Let's say you want to use that power for 3 hours between recharges.  That means a 12 V battery will need to supply 52 A for 3 hours, which on the surface would suggest 156 Ah minimum capacity.  Battery capacity changes with temperature, age, and current, so you have to look at this first approximation figure and decide how to derate it for your situation to get a battery that will serve your needs, whatever those actually are.